# NodeJS JavaScript project with JS decorators (stage 3) and Babel doesn't work

Tags: javascript, babeljs, nodemon, babel-node, javascript-decorators

I am trying to use [JavaScript decorators (stage 3 proposal)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) in my NodeJS project, which is written in JavaScript. However, I am having trouble getting this to work with nodemon and babel together, so that the code will be recompiled when it is changed.

I tried two different `package.json` configurations:

First one:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "start": "npm run build && nodemon dist/app.js"
  },
```

It works the first time only, when I made a change in code it recompiles but I see that runtime is not updated, I see the old result.

Second configuration:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start-nodemon": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/app.js"
  },
```

It doesn't work with decorators and I get the following exception:

```
 @test(true)
    ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

When I remove the decorator it works.

My `.babelrc` config is following:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "sourceMaps": "inline",
      "retainLines": true
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {
      "version": "2022-03"
    }]
  ]
}
```

`app.js` file

```js
import MyModule from "./module.js";

const initializedModule = new MyModule();
const description = initializedModule.getDescription();
console.log(description);
```

`decorators.js` file

```js
export function test(test){
    return function (value, { kind, name }) {
        if (kind === "method" || kind === "getter" || kind === "setter") {
            return function (...args) {
                console.log(test);
                console.log(`starting ${name} with arguments ${args.join(", ")}`);
                const ret = value.call(this, ...args);
                console.log(`ending ${name}`);
                return ret;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and `module.js` file:

```js
import {test} from "./decorators.js";

export default class MyModule {
    @test(true)
    getDescription () {
        return "MyModule Test12";
    }
}
```

How can I properly configure my project, so code will be recompiled and rerun upon changes?

GitHub repository with my project: [babel-test](https://github.com/anatoly314/babel-test)

Thank you!

Comment: On the first command you are transpiling the whole `src` folder and on the second one only `src/app.js` try to change it and see if it helps

Comment: @NirG, now it gives the error: `Cannot find module .../src`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing @babel/node and replacing it with ***babel-register-esm***:

```
npm uninstall @babel/core && npm install --save-dev babel-register-esm
```

Then modify the ***package.json*** file, the scripts section:

```
...
"scripts": {
      "build": "babel src -d dist",
      "start": "yarn build && node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node dist/app.js",
      "start-nodemon": "nodemon --watch \"./src/**/*.js\" --ignore \"node_modules\" --exec \"node --loader babel-register-esm src/app.js\""
   },
...
```

This part

```
node --loader babel-register-esm src/app.js
```

is the most important. It changes the node loader to one that can process ESM features.

And this part:

```
node --loader babel-register-esm src/app.js
```

makes it possible to start a the ESM files.

The expected result is:

```
starting getDescription with arguments 
ending getDescription
MyModule Test12
```

I used yarn instead of npm, and my package.json is:

```
{
 "name": "fixstack",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "dist/app.js",
 "license": "MIT",
 "type": "module",
 "scripts": {
   "build": "babel src -d dist",
   "start": "yarn build && node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node dist/app.js",
   "start-nodemon": "nodemon --watch \"./src/**/*.js\"  --exec \"node --loader babel-register-esm src/app.js\""
 },
   "dependencies": {},
   "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
      "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.20.7",
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
      "babel-register-esm": "^1.2.4",
      "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
    }
 }
```

If you don't want to use **babel-register-esm** and want to call "start", you need to modify the scripts section:

```
  "scripts": {
      "build": "babel src -d dist",
      "start": "yarn build && node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node dist/app.js",
      "start-nodemon": "nodemon --watch \"./src/**/*.js\"  --exec \"yarn start\""
  },
```

Or if you are using NPM instead of YARN:

```
  "scripts": {
      "build": "babel src -d dist",
      "start": "npm run build && node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node dist/app.js",
      "start-nodemon": "nodemon --watch \"./src/**/*.js\" --exec \"npm run start\""
  },
```

Why "--experimental-specifier-resolution=node"?

If you are using type module in your package.json and implementing using import and export instead of CommonJS style, then you need to use this flag (except you use an [explicit path](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers) on your imports, you need to add the .js extension to the filename; i.e: ***import someFunc from './dir/someFile.js'***).
This flag was added in: Node v13.4.0, Node v12.16.0, required until Node v18 (current LTS) at least.

[You could get more information here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/cli.html#--experimental-specifier-resolutionmode)

Comment: Actually your solution gave me an idea how can it be done, but your solution is pretty complex, why you couldn't use something like that?

`
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/app.js",
    "start-nodemon": "nodemon --watch './src/**/*.js' --exec npm run start"
  },
`

Comment: You couldn't run ESM files without --experimental-specifier-solution=node on current LTS (Node 18), it's an experimental feature; and for the same reason, you need a loader that allows transpiling ESM functions along nodemon, that's because of node --loader babel-register-esm src/app.js. If you run nodemon --watch './src/**/*.js' --exec npm run start" is the same as npm run build && node dist/app.js, and the noded command does not have the experimental feature enabled. I am going to edit the answer to show you some variants.

Comment: I edited the answer and tried a setup close to your proposal (I tested it using yarn instead of npm). I removed some unnecesary flags of the original answer.